# Firefox add ons - prevent other extensions from running in background page

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

It seems that other extensions are running code in my extension's background page:
[image]

This is a tracker blocking extension it seems. Any way to disable or prevent this behavior?

Comment: Extensions are sandboxed. Unless you've chosen to run that code other extensions can't just hijack your extension. Maybe you could add the code for `background.js` to the question so we can take a look.

Comment: Firefox's console is showing all extensions. It's a bug in FF.